# how convert string to array MVC3 controller

Tags: string, asp.net-mvc-3, toarray

how string

```
 [null,null,"3",null,null,null]
```

convert to array? in MVC3 (controller)

Comment: Please can you give examples of what you have tried already?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  string[] result = " [null,null,'3',null,null,null]".Replace("[","").Replace("]","").Split(',');
```